# Does Protractor have the same slow find times as Selenium, and if so, is there an in-memory parsing option?

Tags: ruby, selenium, protractor, jsoup, nokogiri

I've used Selenium a lot in the past with Java, Ruby and Groovy, and have often been called upon to read large data tables. Making nested find calls to drill into a table is costly with Selenium, so in the past I've used an in-memory parser like [Nokogiri (Ruby)](https://nokogiri.org/) or [JSoup (Java)](https://jsoup.org/) to read the page into memory, parse it very quickly into objects that are easy to manipulate and read. Then, if I need to interact with any of the objects, I map back to Selenium with only a few find calls, using the information that I've already parsed to narrow it down.

I'm now writing UI Automation using Protractor, although we are not testing Angular apps. I'm wondering if Protractor will present the same problems if I were to perform nested find calls on a large table, and if Protractor or Javascript offer some better way to get at the data faster. If not, is there a library our there for Javascript that's comparable to Nokogiri or JSoup? I'm new to Javascript, so I'm not well versed on what the options are. Thanks!

Comment: Although this question probably will have multiple answers based on opinion, this is my thoughts about using Protractor. You should look into Protractor with TypeScript using async / await. If you are using a non-Angular app, be sure to await waitForAngularEnabled(false) so Protractor does not bootstrap your app with Angular testability. Selenium and Protractor both do not parse the DOM but query the DOM through json wire protocol or the W3C standards. In this regard, I guess it might be slower since it is making an async execute call per query.

Comment: If you are querying a table, look at http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all. Just remember, it is an ElementArrayFinder object and you can use `.filter`, `.map`, .`reduce`, `.each`, etc.

Comment: The top html parsers for javascript are jQuery (browser only) and cheerio (node.js)